# How can I automate high charts and graphs using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, graph, highcharts

Can someone let me know how to automate high charts and graphs using selenium webdriver as the data present in them are dynamic and changes with data inputs given by the user.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the below link helps.

https://github.com/Ardesco/Powder-Monkey/tree/master/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/selenium/graphs

Comment: I think this is a very useful link. Thanks a lot.